# How to update baseAdapter data?

Tags: android, android-adapter, baseadapter

Is there any way to update `BaseAdapter` data except `notifyDataSetChanged()` method?

`notifyDataSetChanged()` method tells adapter to drop current references, but I need those references.

Comment: What do you mean by drop references? which references are you talking about?

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() method tells adapter to remove current references to views in gridView items and load all things from the start

Comment: Why do you want to use old refrences?

Comment: I set animation to one item of gridView and it works fine, but after notifyDataSetChanged the animation does not work because of remove old references